# Saving a product on Admin clears the whole FPC in Magento EE 1.14.1.0

Tags: full-page-cache, redis, aws, ee-1.14.1

I knew this was a problem on the previous versions on Magento EE (e.g. 1.12), but still, Magento EE 1.4.1.0 clears the whole Full Page Cache when saving any product (even a disabled one) from Admin?

On a fairly busy site on AWS I can see 25K GET commands per minute vs 500K SET cpm on a Redis (ElasticCache)!!

[image: 25K GET commands per minute vs 500K SET cpm on a Redis (ElasticCache)]

I traced Redis activities on a quite test site, and this is what I see, the main key being `0e9_REQEST_EE51372B8799AD3A16DD49A1964E4AB7`

When I request the cached page for product A I see:

```
1435257634.091959 [2 172.31.31.125:38722] "hget" "zc:k:0e9_REQEST_EE51372B8799AD3A16DD49A1964E4AB7" "d"
1435257641.610883 [2 172.31.31.125:38723] "hget" "zc:k:0e9_REQEST_EE51372B8799AD3A16DD49A1964E4AB7" "d"
1435257649.431088 [2 172.31.31.125:39672] "hget" "zc:k:0e9_REQEST_EE51372B8799AD3A16DD49A1964E4AB7" "d"
1435257656.495843 [2 172.31.31.125:39238] "hget" "zc:k:0e9_REQEST_EE51372B8799AD3A16DD49A1964E4AB7" "d"
```

That's good.  Then I save product B from Admin (or any other product):

```
1435257671.218878 [2 172.31.33.37:34363] "del" "zc:k:0e9_FPC_SSL_OFFLOADER_HEADER_CACHE" "zc:k:0e9_REQEST_3FD0B9858A5BD4C5983A82B3BA4E891E" "zc:k:0e9_REQEST_EE51372B8799AD3A16DD49A1964E4AB7" "zc:k:0e9_CONTAINER_WISHLISTS_D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E" "zc:k:0e9_REQEST_639EC14FF5C85E1A00496032A1231E21_METADATA" "zc:k:0e9_CONTAINER_WELCOME_ADCE947C7071C72E6355BC3C41B90079" "zc:k:0e9_FPC_DESIGN_EXCEPTION_CACHE" "zc:k:0e9_REQEST_A046F51ADE936C4EFB9B1512BA2B90C1" "zc:k:0e9_E8228F20992B43F6EF7E1CE3252D32AD_2" "zc:k:0e9_REQEST_90C1C30BED5AD6353D867C7F3D5F8564" "zc:k:0e9_REQEST_B7755138804A8360DE7D0D835B496D1A_METADATA" "zc:k:0e9_REQEST_AB2B9C7E9CF0787D0346A28670942F27_METADATA" "zc:k:0e9_E8228F20992B43F6EF7E1CE3252D32AD" "zc:k:0e9_REQEST_063C44E888CA616BDBE25E457B367F0C" "zc:k:0e9_FULL_PAGE_CACHE_SESSION_INFO" "zc:k:0e9_REQEST_9CA83DF96A22C7E7B08DC906DEBC3F3A_METADATA" "zc:k:0e9_813965A26C514B1594EAEC25A38F2ABE" "zc:k:0e9_REQEST_D6A18A31DE59D8CE26FCB251E8E2CAF6_METADATA" "zc:k:0e9_CONTAINER_WISHLINKS_73EDD6326C9C66E02B889380F86479F8"
```

Then I reload the page (now without cache) and I see:

```
1435257730.216541 [2 172.31.31.125:38973] "hget" "zc:k:0e9_REQEST_EE51372B8799AD3A16DD49A1964E4AB7" "t"
1435257730.219902 [2 172.31.31.125:38973] "hmset" "zc:k:0e9_REQEST_EE51372B8799AD3A16DD49A1964E4AB7" "d" "gz:\x1f\x8bx\x01\x8d\xddc\xac\xf0l\x100\xe8c\xdb\xb6m\xdb\xb6m\xdb\xb6m\xdb\xb6m\xdb\xf6y\x8em\xef\xfb}\xebMv\xb3\xbf:i;i\xd2\xa4i\xa6\xf7\xccU\x8f\x9c\x9b\xde+7\xec\xf6%\x82.\xb3\x7f\xeb&\xb5?
```

etc...

Release Notes - Magento Enterprise Edition 1.14.2 - "Resolved several issues related to full-page cache invalidation when products are saved."

So Magento knows about this issue, they've resolved it and apparently they don't have a patch for it.

Now let's see if my good client with Platinum support can get Magento to provide a patch within a decent time frame.

If anyone knows how to get this fixed, please share your profound knowledge! Thanks!

Best

Osvaldo

Answer (score 3):

I think we got a patch for this exact issue and EE 1.13.0.2. Looking at the code, it appears 1.14.1.0 still has the `catalogrule_after_apply` observer that calls `cleanCache`.

Should start on line 378 of app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/etc/config.xml:

```
<catalogrule_after_apply>
    <observers>
        <enterprise_pagecache>
            <class>enterprise_pagecache/observer</class>
            <method>cleanCache</method>
        </enterprise_pagecache>
    </observers>
</catalogrule_after_apply>
```

SUPEE-318 simply changed the method node to:

```
<method>invalidateCache</method>
```

Obviously, test, test and test again--but, seems like the fix. If you have access to support, I would at least confirm that's the correct patch.

**Updated**

Found this observer mentioned in two other posts, linking for reference:

- [Magento Full Page Cahe expire after catalog modification?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/12920/2241)
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/612/2241

Comment: Thanks you. Magento turned around and said that they actually have a patch V3 to deal with that problem, which honestly I would have expected. We'll see how it goes.